# Websocket client send [FIN, ACK] immediately after handshake

Tags: qt, websocket

My project use WebSocket protocol for communication. Server side is implemented in `C`, and for the client side, I use `Qt 4.8.1` to build a simple browser to run HTML and JavaScript code.

I have one problem with Qt framework. After handshake, client size sends [FIN, ACK] immediately to server to notify the closing session as [in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBF4S.png).

I don't know the cause of this problem. I think this is a bug of Qt framework because when I run the client in a Firefox browser, it doesn't happen.
Does anyone have an idea why this is happening ?

Comment: Your question is off-topic until you add a minimum test case. It's also independently possible that your server side is subtly broken and doesn't really implement the websocket spec fully. Note that `QWebSocket` supports protocol 13 only. If your server doesn't, it will close the connection like you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firefox version uses the websocket RFC6455 protocol standards (protocol version 13), QT 4.8.1 uses the websocket hybi-00 protocol standards (no protocol version)
https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-hybi-thewebsocketprotocol-00

Maybe your server implemented correctly RFC6455 protocol standards but incorrectly with hybi-00 protocol standards. Please debug by logging your request and response content (/key3/ and the challenge data). If challenge data that is generated by your server is not matched to the one in the client (QT), client will send [FIN, ACK] immediately to close the socket.